# Select files using include and exclude array of recursive glob patterns

Tags: powershell

I've been given two file glob parameters in JSON, `include` and `exclude`, in the following format:

```
{
    include: ['**/*.md', '**/swagger/*.json', '**/*.yml', 'somedir/*.yml'],
    exclude: ['**/obj/**', 'otherdir/**', '**/includes/**']
}
```

I'm tasked with walking a directory tree to select files according to the include and exclude rules in these formats; this has to be written as a Powershell script.

I've been trying to find a built-in command that supports the double-asterisk, recursive file glob pattern; additionally, since Powershell is converting the JSON to an object, it would be nice if the command parameters could accept an array as input.

I've looked at `Get-ChildItem`, but I'm not sure that I can mimic the glob resolution behavior using `-include`, `-exclude`, and/or `-filter`. I've also looked at `Resolve-Path`, but I'm not sure if the wildcards will work correctly (and I might have to manually exclude paths).

How can I select paths using multiple recursive wildcard file globs in Powershell while excluding other globs? Is there a Powershell command that supports this?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
In these glob patterns, the single asterisk is a regular wildcard. The double asterisk (**), however, is a known standard which denotes a recursive directory search.

For example: the pattern `dir1/*/file.txt` would match:

```
dir1/dir2/file.txt
dir1/dir3/file.txt
```

...but not:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

The pattern dir1/**/file.txt would match everything that the above selector would, but it would also match:

```
dir1/dir3/dir4/file.txt
dir1/dir7/dir9/dir23/dir47/file.txt
```

and so on. So, an exclude glob pattern like `**/obj/**` basically means "exclude anything found in any obj folder found at any point in the directory hierarchy, no matter how deep".

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The double asterisk (`**`) is a known standard; it denotes a recursive directory search. For example, the pattern `dir1/*/file.txt` would match `dir1/dir2/file.txt`and `dir1/dir3/file.txt`, but *not* `dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt`. The pattern `dir1/**/file.txt` would match `dir1/dir2/file.txt`, `/dir1/dir3/dir4/file.txt`, `dir1/dir7/dir9/dir23/dir47/file.txt`, and so on. The single asterisk is just a general wildcard.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I added this explanation to the question.

Comment: PowerShell's file selection and wildcard matching works as described in its documentation pages; implementing other behavior would require designing it in code. Sounds like an interesting project you could make available when you are finished.